# Stream to VLC for iOS via URL Scheme

Tags: ios, vlc

I'm trying to link to the iOS VLC app via its URL scheme. I need to open a FLV file(preferably as a stream, rather than downloading). I have tried `vlc://http://domain.com/path/to/video.flv` which opens VLC with a popup asking if I would like to play or download. Tapping download works, however play doesn't do anything except close the popup(I can get it to eventually work if I tap Play in the popup -> Play in Control Centre -> tap back in VLC). Is there a way to get it to play by directly through the URL?

Bonus points if you figure out how to select the "Scan for Subtitles" option in the "Open Network Stream" section of VLC. ;)

I've looked all over Google and can't find any documentation of the URL scheme. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the vlc:// pseudo protocol is broken in the current 2.6.4 release - it is fixed in 2.6.5 which is currently waiting for review by Apple. I hope that it will be out this week but this is beyond our control.

Generally speaking, I recommend to use another protocol though based on x-callback-url, documented on our wiki: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:IOS/#x-callback-url

Regarding an extra subtitles URL, this is currently not supported. We could add it though, it's just that nobody asked for it so far.

Comment: 1/2 Thanks for your help, @feepk. I didn't necessarily mean a seperate subtitles URL but just some way of enabling a similar functionality to the "Scan for Subtitles" option under the "Open Network Stream" section so that the list of subtitle tracks is displayed to the user. The `vlc://` protocol works fine; VLC opens and prompts for play or download(which now work).

Comment: 2/2 @feepk For the `vlc-x-callback://` protocol, my link is `vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=URL` (I'm assuming I don't have to replace `x-callback-url` with anything as it is shown the same in examples for other apps.) This works fine except if the url has spaces(%20) or percent signs(%25). In these cases, VLC opens but just stays on the main screen. I have tried escaping the percent signs with backslashes however this did not work.

Comment: @Tugzrida, did you find a solution? Seems this bug still exists 5 years later..

Comment: @AaronCoffey hahaha now that’s stretching my memory...IIRC, I just used the vlc:// scheme which pops up the stream/download prompt. It was only for a side project so I didn’t do an extensive search for a better solution.

Comment: @AaronCoffey We didn't add support for external subtitles since then because besides this thread, there was no demand. Both x-callback-url and vlc:// are well supported since 2015.

Comment: @feepk This was about spaces in filenames causing the x-callback-url to fail on ios. I renamed the files, replacing spaces with underscores to make it work, but that may not be possible in certain situations. For example, `vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=http://192.168.1.5:1234/i%20love%20my%20dogs.mp4` will fail, but `vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=http://192.168.1.5:1234/i_love_my_dogs.mp4` will work. I'll look into filing a bug later this week, if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: Oh yes, please file a ticket. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronCoffey no need to rename spaces, simply add `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` to your url

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to add subtitle it has been added in [this commit](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-ios/-/commit/55e27ed69e2fce7d87c47c9342f8889fda356aa9) and can be used like this:

```
vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=http://example.com/dogs.mp4&sub=https://example.com/dogs.srt
```